# Qt memory management for containers

Tags: c++, qt, memory-management, memory-leaks

I know there is many questions about memory management in Qt. Also I read these SO questions:

- [Memory Management in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021125/)
- [Memory management in Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491707/)
- [Qt memory management. What's wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865773/)

But in my case, I confused again!

I have a `QTableWidget` with name `myTable`. I add run-time widgets to it by `setCellWidget`:

```
void MyClass::build()
{
    for (int i=LOW; i<HIGH; i++)
    {
        QWidget *widget = new QWidget(myTable);
        //
        // ...
        //
        myTable->setCellWidget(i, 0, widget);
    }
}
```

Then, I delete all items like below:

```
void MyClass::destroy()
{
    for (int i = myTable->rowCount(); i >= 0; --i)
        myTable->removeRow(i);
}
```

These methods call many times during long time. And `myTable` as the parent of those widgets will live along program's life-time.

Dose method `destroy()` release memory quite and automatically? Or I have to `delete` allocated widgets myself like below?

```
void MyClass::destroy2() // This maybe causes to crash !!
{
    for (int i = myTable->rowCount(); i >= 0; --i)
    {
        QWidget *w = myTable->cellWidget(i, 0);
        delete w;
        myTable->removeRow(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Never delete widgets directly with `delete`.  Resources of widget objects can still be referred to by the underlying window system, causing your application to crash if the window system later on tries to access these resources.  Always use the "deleteLater()" method, which makes Qt delete the widget once it's no longer referenced by the window system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, when in doubt or confused about how to use a class, consult the documentation that should've came with it. Fortunately, [`QTableWidget::setCellWidget()` does in fact come with documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html):

> #### void QTableWidget::setCellWidget ( int row, int column, QWidget * widget )
>
> Sets the given widget to be displayed in the cell in the
>   given row and column, **passing the ownership of the widget to the
>   table** *[emphasis mine]*. If cell widget A is replaced with cell widget B, cell widget
>   A will be deleted. For example, in the code snippet below, the
>   QLineEdit object will be deleted.
>
> ```
>     setCellWidget(index, new QLineEdit);
>     ...
>     setCellWidget(index, new QTextEdit);
> ```

After the call to `myTable->setCellWidget()`, the table now owns the widget you passed into it. That means that `myTable` is responsible for deleting the widgets you pass to `setCellWidget()`. You don't need to do `delete w;` when you're removing rows. Your first `destroy()` function should be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#setCellWidget):

> ```
> void QTableWidget::setCellWidget ( int row, int column, QWidget * widget )
> ```
>
> Sets the given widget to be displayed in the cell in the given row and column, passing the ownership of the widget to the table.
>
> If cell widget A is replaced with cell widget B, cell widget A will be deleted. For example, in the code snippet below, the QLineEdit object will be deleted.

That is, you don't clean up manually, as freeing of resources happens automatically down the Qt object tree, of which your `widget` has become a part.